# Keeping lines that meet the condition in QlikSense script

Tags: where-clause, qliksense

I have a table where I just want to keep the rows where "Attribute 1" value is between the values of "Attribute 2" and "Attribute 3".

I tried with a where clause but it doesn't seem to filter any rows

[Table]:

load *

```
resident [Table] 

    where [Attribute 1]>=[Attribute 2] and [Attribute 1]<=[Attribute 3];
```

Any ideas? I suspect this could be done with an IntervalMatch but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause seems correct. However, you are reading the correct rows from [Table] and adding them to the already existing ones on [Table]. Instead, use:

```
[New table name]:
NOCONCATENATE load * resident [Table] 
where [Attribute 1]>=[Attribute 2] and [Attribute 1]<=[Attribute 3];
```